# Apple Receipt Validation - Auto-Renewable Subscription Error 21004

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

So I am making the call to Apples sandbox receipt verification URL, with my JSON payload containing the receipt-data and the password (shared secret, generated on iTunes Connect).

Every time I make the call I get an status of 21004 back. I have done this so many times now, and every time the same response. I have checked the shared secret key on iTunes Connect and it matches perfectly. I have even regenerated the shared secret and tried another purchase to validate this one, still getting the same response.

Any help is appreciated.

Adam

Comment: Are you sure that you are validating against the correct service? If I remember well there was a production ad a test service.

Comment: Ive double checked this and I am validating against the sandbox service correctly. If I switch to the live service I get the correct status code back that I am validating against the wrong service. After looking into this more it seems to be an issue with Apple and others are posting on their forums with the same issue.

Comment: I'am having the same issue, until yesterday my tests were working and today I am receiving the status 21004 for receipts that I already tested. How did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go there, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72991

1 week that the Sandbox is broken. It's not acceptable for such a company.

No solution on Apple side. They investigate.... Wow... Code must be such a mess

Comment: Thank you for the link. Lets hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Hope Apple can fix this issue soon. I can't test and upload new apps that are using auto-renewable subscription now.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem from apple, they already solved this problem and my tests are working again. For next issues like this, the best option is to write directly in [apple forum in-app-purchase](https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/system-frameworks/in-app-purchase) or if you can replicate the error, please [report a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/)